# How to iterate backwards through dataframe until it meets specified condition, then continue iterating with new value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column called "elements". It either has numbers of length 9 or of length 7 in it's value.
The first row of dataframe is always the one with 9 numbers and the last row is always with 7.

Example:

```
{element:[120000000, 8000000, 120003000, 7000000, 120003333, 120003444, 5000000]
```

I want to create another column called "assigned". That column has to assign values, going from backwards of the dataframe, taking the 7 number value from column "element" until it meets 9 number value. Then use the 7 number value it used before for the last time and go to a new row to start using next 7 number value.

Here is an example:

```
{element:[120000000, 8000000, 120003000, 7000000, 120003333, 120003444, 5000000]}
{assigned:[8000000, 8000000, 7000000, 7000000, 5000000, 5000000, 5000000]}
```

Honestly I am stuck and have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace values greater like `100000000` to missing values and then back filling next values, last convert to integers:

```
df['assigned'] = df['element'].where(df['element'].lt(100000000)).bfill().astype(int)
print (df)
     element  assigned
0  120000000   8000000
1    8000000   8000000
2  120003000   7000000
3    7000000   7000000
4  120003333   5000000
5  120003444   5000000
6    5000000   5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, is to use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) :

```
#is it a 7-digit number ?
m = df["element"].astype(str).str.len().eq(7)
​
df["assigned"] = df["element"].where(m).bfill(downcast="infer")
```

​Output:

```
print(df)

     element  assigned
0  120000000   8000000
1    8000000   8000000
2  120003000   7000000
3    7000000   7000000
4  120003333   5000000
5  120003444   5000000
6    5000000   5000000
```